# How to identify specific input field and set its value to empty

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angular, dom-events

I have this Angular template there are two input fields, I want to identify specific input field in one of two field and set its value to empty not both

```
<input type='text'  [value]='title'>
<input type = 'text' [value]='title'>
<button (click)="title = ''">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you bind both inputs to the same property, then it doesn't matter. If you set `title` to a new value all elements bound to `title` will be updated. Perhaps you actually want to bind them to different properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input #input1 type='text'  [value]='title'>
<input #input2type = 'text' [value]='title'>
<button (click)="input1.value = ''; input2.value = ''">Clear</button>
```

better would be to update the model though as you have it in your question

```
<input #input1 type='text'  [value]='title'>
<input #input2type = 'text' [value]='title'>
<button (click)="title = ''">Clear</button>
```